# Blazor Server throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ...at System.Drawing.ImageConverter..ctor() on Linux

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

With my Blazor Server project, in controllers, I can't use **[FromBody] MyDTO myDTO** as parameter without throwing a **System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Windows.Extensions types are not supported on this platform. at System.Drawing.ImageConverter..ctor()**.

It throws it only on Linux, not on Windows, and my DTO never uses System.Drawing.

I can resolve it by replacing the parameter like this : **[FromBody] JObject myDTO**

But I'm curious to know why I can't use the DTO class.
My project do use System.Drawing.Common at some parts but not in DTOs, and after all it work's with JObject then converting it to MyDTO so really strange issue.

Does anyone have a clue on what's going on here ?

Comment: You should show that DTO class. Any System.Drawing related properties?

Comment: My DTO don't have any System.Drawing properties. My Entity does, but event without mapping the DTO to the Entity the exception occurs.
And mapping is not a problem since it's working when I'm using JObject.
Futhermore my DTO's are in the Shared project which is .net standard 2.1

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Drawing` API is very deeply dependent on Windows.

Getting this exception when running on Linux is correct.

The real question is, since you tagged this with `[blazor]`, why you somehow rely on this API. You shouldn't.

You may have an alternative in System.Drawing.Common but it's not possible to tell.

Comment: Indeed, but my DTO's are in a .Net Standard 2.1 project. Doesn't .Net Standard 2.1 guarantee the cross-platform compatibility ? Is it allowed to do Windows specific in it ?

Comment: Did you add a package?

Comment: OK so I figured out that in my properties I had one type which has a System.Drawing... property. Thanks for your help @henk-holterman, still not clear to me why the Shared project (.Net Standard 2.1) allows the use of one OS specific library.

Comment: And to answer you, the reason why I'm using System.Drawing is because I am moving all the business logic from an old WinForms app. I thought .Net Standard would help me to be cross-platform ready. In some cases it did (e.g. PdfSharp to PdfSharpCore or even System.Drawing.Common), but it still allows some specific like here.

Comment: As long as you don't post more details you won't get a better answer.